# Access Date Query

Tags: sql, date

I have two tables.  1st table is named ClaimsData has a ClaimDate field with the following dates (examples) entered: 10/1/2014, 10/3/2014, 10/5/2014, etc.

The other table is named MonthlyMembershipCounts and has a ReportDate field with the last day of each month in the field - data example:  9/30/2014, 10/31/2015, etc.

ClaimDate
9/1/2014
9/3/2014
10/1/2014
10/5/2014

ReportDateKey
9/30/2014
10/31/2014
11/30/2014

I am trying to write an Access query to match the claim date to the correct month/year in the monthly membership counts table.  How do I do this?  I am not a programmer, but don't have a data analyst and need help!!  And please do not insult me.  I've read some of the answers on here and hesitated to post.  I'm not a programmer.

Comment: Nothing that worked.

Comment: It's helpful if you share how you approached the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the month and year of both the claim dates and report dates, then you can use those values to join them.
Try using the `month()` and `year()` functions on your dates, like:

```
select
  ClaimDate, month(ClaimDate) as ClaimDate_mo, year(ClaimDate) as ClaimDate_yr,
  ReportDate, month(ReportDate) as ReportDate_mo, year(ReportDate) as ReportDate_yr
from
  ClaimsData c inner join
  MonthlyMembershipCounts m on
  month(ClaimDate) = month(ReportDate) and
  year(claimdate) = year(reportDate)
```